# Tkinter Not responding after entering cmd command with os module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cmd, pycharm

I have a button that runs a function. This function is supposed to run 2 cmd commands, and the first cmd command works fine, but the tkinter GUI freezes before the second command can be executed. Is there a way to fix this?

Using pycharm and python 3.9

```
def runspotdl():
    os.system(f'cmd /k "my command here"')
    os.system(f'cmd /k "my second command here"')
```

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What commands do you give.

Comment: first of it is possible to put this function in its own thread which is not suggested for tkinter but plausible, the reason seems to be that the first command is still being executed, the thing is that `os.system` first executes the command and then waits for it to finish (I don't think there is a need for those `cmd /k` in this case) and then writes the next command in the same terminal so basically it is just like a new line for it, also try looking at Popen or sth it is a bit higher level I think and better suited for terminal stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `/k` cmd executes and then remains open.

With `/c` cmd executes and closes.

So, your 1st cmd window upon execution executes and then waits until you close it, and just as you close it, your 2nd cmd command will be executed in the new cmd window.
Also, by all this time, your Tkinter window will freeze since its program is still running for cmd windows. It will unfreeze just as you exit the 2nd cmd window.

So, what I would suggest is, if you are not displaying anything in cmd window using 1st command, then use `/c` for the 1st command and `/k` for the 2nd (to keep it open until you want to exit. Or just add `/c` in every command close the cmd windows after their execution.)
e.g.

```
def runspotdl():
    os.system(f'cmd /c "1st cmd command"')
    os.system(f'cmd /k "2nd cmd command"')
```

Comment: did You test this? because I am pretty sure that `os.system` uses the same terminal. Either how I don't think this will fix the issue because `os.sytem` will only execute when the command executes so it will wait for that still and the gui will freeze anyways. it is just that these commands probably take a while to execute and while that is happening the gui can't update and actually that would mean You would also need to close the terminal after the last coomand but either how I don't think that using `'cmd'` command is necessary in the first place

Comment: Yes, tested it, and `os.system` was using two terminals one after another. I know, this won't fix the issue, all I tried is to explain what was going on. Yes, using a new `cmd` window is unecessary.